# How to change gnome main menu icon?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, icons

I have tried quite a few things now. Nothing seems to work. The tutorial I found are outdated. And its hard to actually find out how gnome actually loads this icon. I have a special theme. I changed the icon in the theme package. Did not work. Open for any hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I achieved that using the tips mentioned in the [Archlinux Wiki](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME_Tips#Change_the_Gnome_Foot_Icon_to_an_Arch_Icon):

1. Download [image] (filename is `starthere.png`)
2. Alternatively get the artwork package using "`pacman -S archlinux-artwork`", this puts all artwork in the `/usr/share/archlinux` directory, and resize your desired logo to 24x24px.
3. Figure out which icon set you're using (Right-click desktop -> Change Background Image -> Theme -> Customize -> Icon). For example, Crux, *GNOME, High Contrast, High Contrast Inverse, Mist, etc.
4. Now make a backup of your current gnome icon in the correct directory. In the example below, I'm using the GNOME icons but adjust the directory structure accordingly for your icon set:

   ```
   # mv /usr/share/icons/gnome/24x24/places/start-here.png
        /usr/share/icons/gnome/24x24/places/start-here.png-virgin
   ```
5. Copy `starthere.png` you just downloaded to the same directory renaming it `start-here.png`.

   ```
   # cp /path/to/starthere.png
        /usr/share/icons/gnome/24x24/places/start-here.png
   ```
6. Restart your gnome-panels and the new Arch logo should be displayed:

   ```
   # pkill gnome-panel
   ```